# Need help updating ASUS P8Z68-V LX BIOS on Windows 8.1

Tags: motherboard, bios

People have suggest to me that I downloaded the "ASUS Update" utility, at this link: http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en-us&m=tools

However, if you go there and select Windows 8.1 64-bit, you can see it suggests 30+ tools, none of which I see mention Windows 8.1. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What took are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: There is apparently an "ASUS Update" tool that lets you flash your BIOS while booted into Windows.

Comment: There is and I had no problem finding the tool when I selected your motherboard.  http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=P8Z68-V+LX&p=1&s=39 like so

Comment: http://puu.sh/aGqIl/4255b28208.png - The second tool here? It mentions "under DOS" which I'm not so familiar with, is it what I should be using?

Comment: There isn't a windows utility for your motherboard use the dos tool.

Comment: The tools page of the current BIOS screens should have an "EZ Flash" entry which can be used to update from a file stored on a flash disk.